# find gravity center of an image containing handwritten characters within a bounding box using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am doing thesis on **"Segmentation of handwritten text document"**. I am now reading and trying to do code on a paper **"Text line and word segmentation of handwritten documents "** by **"G. Louloudis, B. Gatos, I. Pratikakis, C. Halatsis"** using **Matlab**. In this paper at index **"3.2 Hough transform mapping"** i need to find **gravity center** just like this image

[image]

The box is created by using **average height and width** of the character and an exception has been applied on the rightmost block.My image is binary and i have already tried to get the gravity center's co-ordinate by taking the mean of every pixel which is 1(because the image is binary) within each bounding box and trying to draw a red circle to visualize the gravity center.

But I was not satisfied with my result. Is there any efficient way to get the gravity center using Matlab?
If you need this paper, here is the link [Text line and word segmentation of handwritten documents](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f7ddxa60nc4uirr/Text%20line%20and%20word%20segmentation%20of%20handwritten%20documents.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: It's not really a question of efficiency, it's more a question of definition. If you already found the barycenter of each letter, how can we help you ? There are many ways to compute the center of mass, but only one result ...

Comment: ok then. Can you provide me a code or code fragment using this scenario? @Crazy Rat

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try, with this image:

[image]

```
% --- Load image
Img = imread('letter.jpg');

% Convert to double and grey levels 
Img = rgb2gray(double(Img));

% --- Find the barycenter of the thresholded image
[I, J] = find(Img>100);
x = mean(J);
y = mean(I);

% --- Display
hold on
imshow(Img);
caxis auto
scatter(x, y, 'rx');
```

And the result:

[image]

This is just one possibility, there are many ways to get the centroid of an image.

Comment: Just a tip--[`rgb2gray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html) might be a little easier to type if you need to convert to greyscale. Easier to read, at least. :)

Comment: Thanks. The solution was really helpful :) @Crazy Rat

Comment: You're welcome. If you liked the answer you can vote for it or, even better, mark the question as solved suxh that the community knows you don't need help on this anymore